# How to hash a file in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I would like to send my file to the client (like android side) as a hash string(like base64 or any encryption).

But I don't how can I read my file on my host.

for example URL of my file is:

```
example.com/assets/videos/test.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can crypt a file or String like this:

```
$encrypted = Crypt::encryptString('example.com/assets/videos/test.mp4');
```

And you can decrypt it like this:

```
$decrypted = Crypt::decryptString($encrypted);
```

Do not forget to use this at the header:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;
```

For more information I would recommend checking out the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/encryption)